# Grep full URLs (with all slashes) from file

Tags: linux, grep

I wrote a grep command in order to grep URLs which starts with http/https from file.
I used a regex which is:
`(https?:\/\/)([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?`

For the string `http://google.com/hello/from/here`, I wanted to get the full URL.
However, when I ran the script the output was `http://google.com/`.
How can I force the grep command to find everthing between each slashes (until the end of the line or the first space)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `([a-z\.]{2,6})`? ".museum" isn't the longest TLD anymore.

Comment: [edit] your question to have a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input (e.g. your target URLs in context surrounded by other strings) and expected output, otherwise we're guessing blindly at your needs.